# Java JButton shows in one panel but not the other

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I'm building a very basic GUI for a faux sales system and I am trying to show two screens ("Sales" and "Home") both with buttons to go to the other jpanel, but also with a "Quit" button on both to close the application.

I am using the following code, I thought I could use the same code for the other buttons as for the "Quit" button however Quit only shows up on the Sales page, not on the Homepage.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PHPSRSFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 115;
    public static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30;
    public static final int HEADING_WIDTH = 350;
    public static final int HEADING_HEIGHT = 35;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel homePanel, salesPanel;
    private JButton salesButton, homeButton, quitButton;

    public PHPSRSFrame()
    {
        // Create the frame for the program
        frame = new JFrame("PHP Sales Reporting System");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Create each panel (page), use null layout for absolute locations
        homePanel = new JPanel();
        homePanel.setLayout(null);
        salesPanel = new JPanel();
        salesPanel.setLayout(null);

        // Create Homepage heading
        JLabel lblPhpSalesReporting = new JLabel("Welcome");
        lblPhpSalesReporting.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 24));
        lblPhpSalesReporting.setBounds(WIDTH/2-HEADING_WIDTH/2, 50, HEADING_WIDTH, HEADING_HEIGHT);

        // Create Sales heading
        JLabel lblSales = new JLabel("Sales");
        lblSales.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 24));
        lblSales.setBounds(WIDTH/2-100/2, 50, 100, HEADING_HEIGHT);

        // Create button to go to sales screen
        salesButton = new JButton("Sales");
        salesButton.setBounds(WIDTH/2-BUTTON_WIDTH/2, 150, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        salesButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Create button to return to home screen
        homeButton = new JButton("Home");
        homeButton.setBounds(20, 20, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        homeButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Create button to quit the whole program
        quitButton = new JButton("Quit");
        quitButton.setBounds(650, 500, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        quitButton.addActionListener(this);

        // Add components to Homepage
        homePanel.add(lblPhpSalesReporting);
        homePanel.add(salesButton);
        homePanel.add(quitButton);

        // Add components to Sales page
        salesPanel.add(homeButton);
        salesPanel.add(lblSales);
        salesPanel.add(quitButton);

        frame.setContentPane(homePanel);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        JButton button = (JButton) ae.getSource();
        // Go to sales page
        if (button == salesButton)
        {   
            frame.remove(homePanel);
            frame.setContentPane(salesPanel);
        }
        // Go to homepage
        else if (button  == homeButton)
        {
            frame.remove(salesPanel);
            frame.setContentPane(homePanel);
        }
    // Quit the application
    else if (button == quitButton) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // Redo the frame
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
}   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new PHPSRSFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anybody please tell me what I am missing/have done wrong that is causing the home button to ONLY appear on the sales page?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't add the same `JButton` to two different Parent Containers. This will result in making only the last add call valid.
You need to create two different JButtons that could share the same ActionListener.

Or when switching the `JPanels` you could remove the button from the dissapearing and add it to the appearing frame.

```
homePanel.add(quitButton);  // add to home panel
[...]
//salesPanel.add(quitButton); // don't add to sales panel
[...]
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    [...]
    if (button == salesButton)
    {   
        homePanel.remove(quitButton);
        salesPanel.add(quitButton);
        [...]
    }
    else if (button  == homeButton)
    {
        salesPanel.remove(quitButton);
        homePanel.add(quitButton);
        [...]
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much.
I have created two different quit buttons for each page and it now works as expected.